# When putting together my yacc and lex file, yacc is not recognizing my tokens. Why?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am attempting to put together a yacc, lex, and semantics file to be able to recognize an input file of the following format:

```
    x = 55;
    y = 45.5;
    z = - ( x + y );
```

I feel as if everything is in order, and I get no errors when I compile, but yacc and lex do not seem to recognize anything.

Here is my lex file:

```
    %{
    #include "IOMngr.h"
    #include "y.tab.h"
    
    #define YY_INPUT(buf, result, max_size) \
    { int c = getNextSourceChar(); \
    result = (c == EOF) ? YY_NULL : (buf[0] = c, 1); \
    }
    
    %}
    
    letter [A-Za-z]
    digit [0-9]
    
    %%
    
    ({digit}+).({digit}+)        {return FLOAT;}
    {letter}({letter}|{digit})*  {return Ident;}
    {digit}{digit}*              {return INT;}
    "+"                          {return '+';}
    "-"                          {return '-';}
    "="                          {return '=';}
    "*"                          {return '*';}
    ")"                          {return ')';}
    "("                          {return '(';}
    
    [ ]                          {}
    \t                           {}
    \r                           {}
    \n                           {}
    
    .                            {
                                   writeIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum());
                                   writeMessage("Illegal Character in lex");
                                 }
    
    %%
    
    int yywrap() {
      return 1;
    }
```

Here is my yacc file:

```
    %{
      #include "SymTab.h"
      #include "semantics.h"
      #include "IOMngr.h"
      #include <string.h>
      #include <stdio.h>
      
      extern int yylex();
      extern char *yytext;
      extern int yyleng;
      extern int yyerror(char *);
    
      extern SymTab *table;
      extern SymEntry *entry;
      
    %}
    
    
    %union {
      struct number *value;
      int integer;
      float floatnum;
      char * string;
    }
    
    %type <string> Id
    %type <value> Expr
    %type <value> Term
    %type <value> Factor
    %type <integer> INT
    %type <floatnum> FLOAT
    
    %token Ident
    %token FLOAT
    %token INT
    
    %%
    
    Prog            :  StmtSeq                 {printSymTab();};
    StmtSeq         :  Stmt StmtSeq            {};
    StmtSeq         :                          {};
    Stmt            :  Id '=' Expr ';'         {storeVar($1, $3);};
    Expr            :  Expr '+' Term           {$$ = doADD($1, $3);};
    Expr            :  Term                    {$$ = $1;};
    Term            :  Term '*' Factor         {$$ = doMULTIPLY($1, $3);};
    Term            :  Factor                  {$$ = $1;};
    Factor          :  '-' Factor              {$$ = doNEGATE($2);};
    Factor          :  '(' Expr ')'            {$$ = $2;};
    Factor          :  Id                      {$$ = getVal($1);};
    Factor          :  INT                     {$$ = getInt($1);};
    Factor          :  FLOAT                   {$$ = getFloat($1);};
    Id              :  Ident                   {$$ = strdup(yytext);};
    
    %%
    
         int yyerror(char *s) {
           printf("YYERROR STRING: %s\n", s);
           writeIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum());
           writeMessage("Illegal Character in YACC");
           return 1;
         }
```

Here is my semantics.h:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    struct number {
      int ival;
      float fval;
      char type;
    };
    
    void printSymTab();
    void storeVar(char * name, struct number *v);
    struct number *doADD(struct number * n1, struct number * n2);
    struct number *doMULTIPLY(struct number *n1, struct number *n2);
    struct number *doNEGATE(struct number *n1);
    struct number *getVal(char * name);
    struct number *getInt(int num);
    struct number *getFloat(float num);
```

And lastly here is my IOMngr.h in case it is relevant:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    #define MAXLINE 1024
    
    int openFiles(char * sourceName, char * listingName);
    
    void closeFiles();
    
    char getNextSourceChar();
    
    void writeIndicator(int column);
    
    void writeMessage(char * message);
    
    int getCurrentLineNum();
    
    int getCurrentColumnNum();
```

The problem lies somewhere in the yacc or lex file though.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Add debug printing to your lexical analyzer before each of the `return` statements.  Add debug printing to your `YY_INPUT` macro.  One of those should tell you what's going wrong.  Write diagnostics to `stderr`; include newlines at the end of each message.  The four white space rules could be combined into one, `[ \r\t\n] { }`, but that's tangential to your problem.  (See [`#define` macro for debug printing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/1/1644868/15168) for how to use macros for debug printing.)

Comment: @johathan: That URL doesn't go anywhere. But you can achieve the same effect with a lot less work by turning on lex debugging; it's only necessary to add `-d` to the lex invocation. You can get even better debugging output by also enabling yacc/bison traces, adding `-t` to the yacc/bison invocation and setting the global `yydebug` to 1.

Comment: @Wesley: probably not your problem, but your prototype for `getNextSourceChar` has return type `char` instead of `int`, which could make returning EOF awkward (depending on the signedness of `char` on the platform on which you are compiling). Also, reading characters one by one is a huge slowdown for flex; you should avoid it in production code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with your token decoding and use of `yytext`.  You do not extract the values of INT/FLOAT/Ident tokens in your .l file; you instead access `yytext` elsewhere (in the action `Id : Ident {$$ = strdup(yytext);};` and we can assume in your getInt/getFloat functions.)

The problem is that that is not safe -- yytext points at the last token extracted, which may be the one *after* the token you actually want, as bison uses one token lookahead.  In general it is never safe to access yytext from your yacc actions (or from functions called from yacc actions), as you don't know which token you're going to get.

Instead, you need to decode the associated token value in the .l file and assign it to yylval:

```
({digit}+).({digit}+)        { yylval.floatnum = atof(yytext); return FLOAT; }
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*  { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return Ident; }
{digit}{digit}*              { yylval.integer = atoi(yytext); return INT; }
```